# gtsummary >> tbl_regression >> show_single_row

Tags: r, gtsummary

I want the result to display one line on several variables and I get an error, what is wrong with the code?

this work fine:

```
t3 = x %>%
dplyr::select(meanq_dic,sug_bikur, gil, kod_min,kod_migzar_mirpaa,sug_ta,
                        zion_sotzio,Vetek_m_t,Vetek_baaretz_g,sw_Obesity,
                        sw_Smoking,pscore)%>%
glm(meanq_dic ~ 
      sug_bikur+kod_min+kod_migzar_mirpaa+sug_ta+zion_sotzio+Vetek_baaretz_g+Vetek_m_t+
      sw_Obesity+sw_Smoking+pscore, family = binomial, .) %>%
tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, show_single_row=sw_Obesity )%>%
  add_global_p()%>%
  bold_labels()%>%
  bold_p()
```

this does not

```
t4 = x %>%
dplyr::select(meanq_dic,sug_bikur, gil, kod_min,kod_migzar_mirpaa,sug_ta,
                        zion_sotzio,Vetek_m_t,Vetek_baaretz_g,sw_Obesity,
                        sw_Smoking,pscore,late)%>%
glm(meanq_dic ~sug_bikur+kod_min+kod_migzar_mirpaa+sug_ta+zion_sotzio+Vetek_baaretz_g+
                Vetek_m_t+sw_Obesity+sw_Smoking+pscore+late , family = binomial, .) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, show_single_row=list(sw_Obesity,
                        sw_Smoking)  )%>%
  add_global_p()%>%
  bold_labels()%>%
  bold_p()
```

```
Error: Error in `show_single_row=` argument input. Select from ‘(Intercept)’, ‘sug_bikur’, ‘kod_min’, ‘kod_migzar_mirpaa’, ‘sug_ta’, ‘zion_sotzio’, ‘Vetek_baaretz_g’, ‘Vetek_m_t’, ‘sw_Obesity’, ‘sw_Smoking’, ‘pscore’, ‘late’
```

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
[rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Use c() instead of list() to select the variables